# What to do when the official Rubik's cube solving sequence breaks?

Tags: rubiks-cube, minimum-solve, solvability

So, the official guide shows you exactly how to solve the white cross, first layer, etc. but on the second layer, assume you've completed every little square but one (and edge) and that there's 2 edges if that colour on the bottom face. Making it (or at least seem to be) impossible. What do you do in this case, because I cannot seem to find it online.

Here's an example:

[image: Cube Position]

Comment: Can you provide a picture? It's a little hard to tell exactly what you mean.

Comment: @Rob Maybe another time if I can, what I mean is that every square in the 2 layers is correct, but 1, which isn't a corner piece or middle piece, it's an edge, but the 2 remaining is on the bottom face, not the 3rd layer on the side.

Comment: No, say every layer 1 has a full white face, and all the other squares on the side are perfectly coloured. Now move up a layer and say they are all perfectly coloured BUT 1. Let's use red for example, now assume both of the remaining red edges are at the bottom of the cube. The official sequence tells us how to move 1 from the 3rd layer on the side, if the 2 is on the bottom, you can't move them properly. This is not covered in the guide.

Comment: @Rob Clear now?

Comment: Would it be possible for you to take a screenshot of the situation you're talking about from [a virtual Rubik's cube](http://www.mathplayground.com/rubikscube.html) and attach it?

Comment: @Emrakul [this link](http://ruwix.com/online-rubiks-cube-solver-program/) looks like it might be easier to work with

Comment: @Emrakul I can try :D

Comment: @Rob I've added a picture in the question.

Comment: @Rob Sorry about that, fixed now lol.

Comment: @Rob Oops that bottom left one on the blue face should be orange.

Comment: @Rob Fixed! It's so easy to overlook a mistake when painting a virtual cube.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example picture, the sequence isn't broken at all - the cubule you need to insert into the second layer is already below the blue face where it needs to be. If you perform `D' R' D R D F D' F'` with blue in front, the second layer will be solved.

Your confusion comes from still treating the cube in terms of stickers instead of cubules. The cubule that's currently in the blue-orange corner is entirely the wrong cubule, not just one sticker off.

Comment: This doesn't match what I was trying to say...

Comment: Basically, you need the entire blue-orange cubule in the blue-orange position; you can't have blue-yellow and somehow expect to "insert" the orange in.

Comment: Got it! You fixed it! Thanks, I had the wrong blue there :D Accept!

Comment: @warspyking As an addendum, it actually might be useful for you to disassemble the puzzle once you're done. You'll see pretty clearly that stickers aren't freely interchangeable.

Comment: @Emrakul I know that, I saw that I had a blue and never noticed how mistaken I was.

Comment: It takes some practice.

Comment: @Joe Z. On to the next layer! :D

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to understand exactly what situation your cube is in based on your description, but I'll do my best...

Here is an online guide that tells you what you need to do http://www.rubiks.com/blog/how-to-solve-the-rubiks-cube

Side note: I solve the cube beginning with the bottom layer, so by "top layer" I am referring to the part which is currently unsolved (that may be your bottom layer?)

Based on your description, I believe you are in step four of that tutorial, completing the second layer. There are several possible situations I think you could be in (based on the confusing description), most of which are solveable. I interpret your description as there are either one or multiple pieces that are in the right places, but rotated incorrectly (or two pieces on the second layer are in swapped positions).

This situation occurs if you brought the edge piece down from the top border using the wrong algorithm mentioned on the website (or if it began in this unfortunate position). In either case, use one of the two algorithms provided on the website to bring a top piece (which belongs on top) down into the incorrect spot, the where the piece you are concerned about is currently located (which moves the correct piece back up to the top layer). Then, bring the correct piece down into its original spot with the **other** algorithm from the website. This time it should be rotated correctly.

Note: If this is a used or old Rubik's cube, it is also possible that at one point the cube burst or was purposely taken apart, and then accidentally put back together in a way that makes the cube unsolveable. If so, I think you would never encounter any difficulties until later in the solving process, but it's a possibility.

Comment: Does this match the image? Also, I solve the "top layer" first. I don't get your answer.

Comment: I was correct; please follow my above link to the site and follow the algorithm to solve. The blue and yellow edge belongs on the currently unsolved top/bottom layer, and the blue and orange piece is currently in the correct position to be brought down to the middle layer using the algorithm on the website. Sorry I can't comment on you question. Happy Solving!

Comment: I don't get it... What moves do I use to bring it down to it's rightful spot.